# Testing the model in Play framework: initial-data.yaml failing validation

Tags: playframework-2.0, yaml

I'm trying to set up JUnit tests in my Play application like in the sample zentasks application included with Play, using the initial-data.yaml file.

My application has Users, and a User can create a Load, so Load has a many-to-one association with User. In my Load.java model, I have the code:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="uid",nullable=false)
public User user;
```

and in User.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
public Set<Load> loads;
```

In initial-data.yaml in app/conf/, I'm trying to set up two Loads with Users like so, to use as test data:

users:

```
- !!models.User
    id:         1
    username:   rachael
    password:   secret
    name:       Rachael P
    email:      email@gmail.com
    userclass:  1

- !!models.User
    id:         2
    username:   wildbill
    password:   secret
    name:       Billy Z
    email:      email2@gmail.com
    userclass:  1

- !!models.User
    id:         3
    username:   sammydude
    password:   secret
    name:       Sammy
    userclass:  0
```

loads:

```
- !!models.Load
    id:                 1
    user:               !!models.User
                            id: 3
    created:            2013-1-4 10:00:00 -05:00
    modified:           2013-1-5 15:30:00 -05:00
    invoiceNumber:      324
    billOfLadingNumber: 435d
    proNumber:          334mqr86547tr
    status:             PENDING
    rawCharge:          25.00
    totalWeight:        50.00
    numPallets:         1
    units:              box(es)

- !!models.Load
    id:                 2
    user:               !!models.User
                            id: 2
    created:            2013-1-4 10:00:00 -05:00
    modified:           2013-1-5 15:30:00 -05:00
    invoiceNumber:      328
    billOfLadingNumber: 97re
    proNumber:          43y43j5yh4
    status:             PENDING
    rawCharge:          60.00
    totalWeight:        400.00
    numPallets:         1
    units:              box(es)
```

In app/Global.java, the lines `Ebean.save(all.get("users"));` and `Ebean.save(all.get("loads"));` compile without error, but I get a `validation failed for: models.User` error on the following lines:

```
    for(Object load : all.get("loads")) {
        // Insert load/user relation
        Ebean.saveAssociation(load, "user");
    }
```

Can anybody spot the error? I've been over and over the code, but as far as I know I'm using the right method to save the association. I can't think of another reason why it would save the Users and Loads separately no problem but error when saving the association.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help, but don't use `User` as the table name since it is a keyword in many database server:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myUserTable")
public class User extends Model {
...
}
```

Change it accordingly in your mappings.